# Install CentOS 7 using text mode

Tags: linux, centos, system-installation

I have remote server without GUI support. How can I install `CentOS 7 there?

The `CentOS 7` is mandatary and I can't switch to another OS or distribution.

I get following text at the end. I able to mount CD but I don't know what to do next. `FreeBSD` has `bsdinstall` which works in text mode. `Debian` can also be installed in text mode  without any problems.

```
 (?- 
 //\   Core is distributed with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
 v_/_           www.tinycorelinux.com

tc@box:~$ Switched to clocksource tsc
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CentOS 7 has an option to install in text mode.

When you see `install centos` menu option press the tab key, add `text` to the end of any existing installer command line arguments and then press the return key.

This will tell the installer (Anaconda) to install the OS in text mode.

Comment: Thank you, I've found that I used wrong `initrd`. I was able to install after replacing it with `initrd` for `pxeboot`. But how should I run the OS? Where can I download the kernel and `initrd` to run os in normal mode? I'm sorry for these noob questions.

Comment: Unless you have set up a `pxe` server, using `pxeboot` will not work.  Just download regular install media,burn to DVD, boot from DVD, and go from there

Comment: For VM I use bhyve/xhyve, also these files are required by Xen to boot Linux.

Comment: My final result: I able to install ubuntu server and centos. However centos doesn't work only because of some wierd bug in AES module (it's opened in the official issue tracker). It works from time to time, but it's not stable and this happens only in specific CentOS(7)/Red Hat across limited number of architectures like MBA.

Comment: Does the text you quote `install centos` - menu appear only on systems **without any graphic support** (i.e. no framebuffer, raster output)?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are directly connected to the console of your headless system, just add

```
console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

to the above mentioned boot command. This will redirect the output to the serial console (bear in mind, that 115200 is the console speed). So the complete line would be

```
linux text console=ttyS0,57600n8
```

for a console output with a speed of 57600 baud.

It must be the same speed as it is configured in your Putty session under serial speed. In case you are connecting to the console from a unix-like-system (Linux, BSD, OS X) it can be done with screen:

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 115200,cs8
```

Answer (score 1):

To use text mode install, you can also press ESC when you see `install centos`. At the `boot:` prompt, type `linux text`.

Comment: Thank you for a share of an another method to switch to text mode install. The important thing was I want to install a linux in headless interactive mode when I had only serial line attached to a VM without a graphics card installed.